# Confusion about python itertools.tee - will iterators generated by itertools.tee affect each other?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, iterable

Python version: 3.9.7

I saw such an introduction about `itertools.tee` on the [official documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

> Return n independent iterators from a single iterable.

But i found that iterator generated by `itertools.tee` seems to affect others. Here is my code:

```py
from itertools import tee


def func():
    g = (x for x in range(3, 100, 2))
    while True:
        n = next(g)
        yield n
        g = filter(lambda x: x % n > 0, g)
        g1, g2 = tee(g, 2)

        # for i in range(10):
        #     next(g1)
        g = g2


gg = func()
print([next(gg) for i in range(10)])
# Output:
# [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]
```

But, if i uncomment `line 12 and 13`, the output will changed like this:

```
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
```

Can anyone tell me the reason? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

The iterators returned by `itertools.tee` are independent in the sense that they can be advanced without affecting each other's positions in the data stream. They are not completely independent in the sense you seem to have expected. It would be impossible to make them *that* independent.

Your code has a bug. This:

```
g = filter(lambda x: x % n > 0, g)
```

doesn't mean what you think it does. `n` is looked up lazily. As soon as the value of `n` changes, the filter will be using the wrong value.

When you uncomment the commented-out loop, that loop immediately advances one of the tee iterators 10 times, which advances the underlying filter iterator 10 times to produce values. These values are computed with the correct `n`, since `n` hasn't been reassigned yet, and the values are stored in the tee's underlying storage for the other tee iterator to use. This is enough to hide the lazy `n` bug.

With the loop commented out, each filter iterator is advanced lazily. The wrong `n` is used almost every time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think i should use a closure function instead. But, how can i view values in `g` without affect it if itertools.tee doesn't meet my needs?